# Merge commits belonging to a subdirectory of a branch to master

Tags: git, git-rebase

After looking around I was surprised that this question wasn't answered for my specific problem already.

I have a repository with two branches, one of which is the `master` branch, which is also published to a remote repository.

My second branch is called `preparation`, I checked this one out in the past, and made some commits to it. Unfortunately I made commits to a subdirectory which I don't want to announce publicly yet.
There were some changes, though, that would make sense to be pulled into master. Those changes only belong to a subdirectory of the `preparation` branch.

Here's a picture of the commit history. I basically made the mistake to commit changes to a subdirectory of branch `preparation` that I now don't want to have in `master`, nor the remote repository at all.

What can I do to have the commit history, but not the false commit?

Thank you!

Comment: If reaching everyone who might have the bad commit is easy and they haven't had a chance to get too invested in it, just `git checkout -B prepare ':/Added date'', make the commits you should have made, force-push and have everyone refetch.

Comment: Hard to parse what you're asking. Not sure what you mean by a subdirectory of a branch, since a branch isn't a directory like it is in CVS/SVN. Do you want changes in one branch to be added to a different location in a different branch? Are the good changes in the same commits as bad changes? You might need an interactive cherry-pick if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but maybe you just want to remove one commit labelled as "New talk" from the history that you plan to merge.

If that is so, you can use interactive rebasing. To skip one commit during interactive rebasing just remove it from the list of commit.

I assume that commit "New talk" is the commit number five when you run `git log`.
I assume also that your repo is clean.

Here is the procedure.

First create a new branch called `new-preparation` (just in case something goes wrong):

```
git checkout -b new-preparation preparation
```

Now run the interactive rebasing:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

Git should start vim with the last five revisions shown (the one that you want to get rid off should be at the very top):

```
pick SHA-1 - oldest of five commits - the one labelled "New talk"
pick SHA-1 
pick SHA-1
pick SHA-1
pick SHA-1 - newest of five commits
```

Delete the first line. The vim's contents should look like:

```
pick SHA-1 
pick SHA-1
pick SHA-1
pick SHA-1 - newest of five commits
```

save the file and exit.

Git should rebase the four remaining commits.

You should now have your branch without the commit "New talk".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand how `git` works.  And that is horribly clouding what you are describing.

You can't commit changes to directory or a subdirectory. Say this with me: Changes are committed to branches.

The mistake you made was mixing the usage of a branch for commits that were unrelated.  Branches in `git` are cheap.  A best practice is to create a `branch` for every single feature you work on.

That aside, let's say you did need the earlier work to be present before you uncovered the need to make this change and wanted it fixed in both places.

That is quite common and has been answered in many different ways.  You will need to do a rebase-onto commit.
Take a look at the git book documentation for rebases: http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html

In short, you want to take commits from some point forward but skipping a bunch of commits between the common ancestor of your branch and the spot you want to merge to.

In this case assuming it's just one commit you're going to need to do something like this:
`git rebase --onto origin/master HEAD~ preparation`

That said, I suggest reading the material first and gaining an understanding of what you are doing.